# Can't bind data to src attribute of img tag in a jhipster - angular 2 project

Tags: angular, jhipster

I've changed from raw-loader to html-loader as the issue: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5333

then it works if I code as below:

```
 <div class="img">
            <img src="../../content/images/lotto-euro1.png" alt="Logo here"/>
            <p>{{imgSrc}} here </p>
    </div>
```

**When I bind data to src as below, it doesn't work.**

```
this.imgSrc = "../../content/images/lotto-euro1.png";

<div class="img">
    <img src={{imgSrc}} alt="Logo here"/>
    <p>{{imgSrc}} here </p>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="img">
                <img [src]="imgSrc" alt="Logo here"/>
                <p>{{imgSrc}} here </p>
            </div>
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: `[src]="imgSrc"` should work.. any error in console.?

Comment: inspect as below: <img alt="Logo here" ng-reflect-src="../../content/images/lotto-euro1.png" src="../../content/images/lotto-euro1.png"> but the image can't display. I think this is issue in config webpack, but I don't know how to fix

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `src={{imgSrc}}` to `src="{{imgSrc}}"` in the first case or `[src]` to `[attr.src]` in the second case. If it doesn't work, give us an html code of the img.

Comment: @CongThanh did you find a solution?